# How to capture the output of executed command (python paramiko )?

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, stdout, paramiko

I am executing certain commands and would like to capture the output of the same.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,username="username",password="pwd")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("whoami")
out = stdout.read()
print out           # prints username
print stdout.read() # prints nothing, why is it so ?
                    # Instance #1

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("kill -9 1111")
out = stdout.read()
print out #prints nothing. expected as it doesn't capture if it's successful
# print out # should print "-bash: kill: (1111) - No such process" , if it doesn't exist 
#--> Instance #2
```

In Instance #1, why print stdout.read() , prints nothing ?

In Instance #2, How to capture such outputs/response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### instance #1

```
out = stdout.read()
print stdout.read()
```

The first `stdout.read()` has already consumed all the output so the second `stdout.read()` returns nothing.

#### instance #2

Usually error messages would print to *stderr* so you should use `stderr.read()` to get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It probably prints nothing because stdout is empty because of an error in the execution.
Try printing stderr instead of stdout